# dnsmasq redirect domain to another

Tags: dns, domain, redirection, dnsmasq

what i'm trying to do is redirect domain to another domain for example when i type www.google.com redirect to www.facebook.com but main idea is to keep the url the same that means http://www.google.com

```
192.168.1.99 www.facebook.com
192.168.1.98 www.microsoft.com microsoft.com
192.168.1.97 www.any.domain any.domain
```

this works but the url still change

so is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with just DNSMasq - It's non-trivial to do, but if you change the host to point to an IP you control and add a proxy server (possibly one which can rewrite the content like Privoxy) you probably hack this into being.

It gets even harder if you try do it for secure sites.